# PHP: Why can't I update a parent class's protected properties?

Tags: php

I have a parent class and a handful of children that extend that parent.

What I'm trying to do is set some properties of the child that extend to the parent.

Here's an example.

```
class Activity {
    protected static $activity;
    protected static $data_sql;
    protected static $field_prefix;
    protected static $field_names;

    //gets the data on a specific activity
    public function get_data() {
        $data = \DB::selectOne(self::$data_sql, [':id' => self::$activity['id']], \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->format_data($data);
    }
}

class Post extends Activity {
    protected static $activity;
    protected static $data_sql = "SELECT * FROM post_activity_data WHERE activity_id = :id";
    protected static $field_prefix = 'post_';
    protected static $field_names = [
        //set a handful of items
    ];

    public function __construct($activity) {
        self::$activity = $activity;
    }
}

$data = new activity\Post($activity);
$new_data = $data->get_data();
```

In `Post`, it extends `Activity`, but when I run `get_data` it doesn't use the variables set in the child class and instead tries to use the empty variables from `Activity`.

What am I missing here to properly do this?

Comment: see [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Well that's perfect. Works exactly how I was expecting it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem right. You create a new instance of a class:

```
$data = new activity\Post($activity);
```

But then in the constructor, you set a static variable. Which means it will be shared by all classes. So if later you do this:

```
$data = new activity\Post('');
```

You will erase the changes you made earlier.

With the setup you have, I don't think it makes sense to use static variables (which are a bit like global variables, so should be used with care). Instead, you could use simple member variables:

```
class Activity {
    protected $activity;
    protected $data_sql;
    protected $field_prefix;
    protected $field_names;

    //gets the data on a specific activity
    public function get_data() {
        $data = \DB::selectOne($this->$data_sql, [':id' => $this->$activity['id']], \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->format_data($data);
    }
}

class Post extends Activity {
    protected $activity;
    protected $data_sql = "SELECT * FROM post_activity_data WHERE activity_id = :id";
    protected $field_prefix = 'post_';
    protected $field_names = [
        //set a handful of items
    ];

    public function __construct($activity) {
        $this->$activity = $activity;
    }
}

$data = new activity\Post($activity);
$new_data = $data->get_data();
```

Comment: Good point about the risk of statics and sound advice overall, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the usage of static properties. Switching to using `$this` instead worked perfectly. Thanks!